# The $L_p(X, \mu)$ space for $\mu$ having countable basis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(X, \sigma, \mu)$ be measurable space. We say that $\mu$ has a countable basis if there is countable subset $\nu \subset \sigma$ and for any $\epsilon >0$ and $A \in \sigma$ there exists $B \in \nu$ such that $\mu( A \triangle B) < \epsilon$.

Now the exercise is to show that $L_p(X, \mu)$ and $L_p^0(X, \mu)$ are separable ($L_p^0$ is preimage of $L_p$ before we identify all functions which coinside almost everywhere).

I suppose we should take linear combinations of indicators of sets from $\nu$ as the dense set. If I am right, I got to prove that for any $f \in L_p$, $\epsilon > 0$ there is $g$ which is linear combination of indicators such that $\int_X |f(t) - g(t)|^p d\mu(t) < \epsilon$. By the way, what's the difference  between  the proof for $L_p$ and $L_p^0$?

Comment: I suppose you already know that the simple functions are dense in $L_p$.  So try approximating a simple function by a linear combination of indicators from $\nu$ (with rational coefficients, so that your set is countable).  It is pretty straightforward.  The proofs for $L_p$ and $L_p^0$ will look identical since for all analysis purposes the two spaces behave the same.

Comment: @ Nate Eldredge, I know the fact that $\int_X f(t) d\mu(t)$ can be approximated by simple functions, but I don't know how to prove that $\int_X |f(t)|^p d\mu(t)$ too. I mean, for $f(t)$ integrable $|f(t)|^p$ may not be.
  So, I know just that the simple functions are dense in $L_1$